# whats the difference between these two style.cc files

Tags: css, sass

A developer recently changed the formatting of my style.css file from:

```
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 10px 0 10px;
  height: 80px;
}
.header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 3rem;
}
.header h3 a {
  color: #636c72;
}
.header ul.nav {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

to this:

```
.header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 10px 0 10px;
  height: 80px; }
  .header h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 3rem; }
    .header h3 a {
      color: #636c72; }
  .header ul.nav {
    margin-top: 4px; }
```

**My Question**

I can see that the new developer has changed the formatting to a nested style which is fine I guess BUT I'm wondering if this will have any implications on my app which currently uses SCSS? More specifically I'm wondering if the new developer has used SCSS to do this or he's introduced something new to my project which I don't know about.

I have zero knowledge of css hence the question.

Comment: There are only whitespace changes between those two versions. Whitespace is not important for the evaluation of CSS. It is a very unusual way of formatting, though.

Comment: No it's not unusual. Just compiled using `nested` option using sass.

Comment: So sass and scss was still used to generate this code?

Comment: Yes, no one is going to do that manually. :)

Comment: @muecas praise the lord, thanks for confirming :)

Comment: haha, no problem

Comment: I wonder why SASS is doing that. The first format is much more readable, because you can more readily see where one style set ends and another one begins. Also the second one may look more compact, but it actually is longer in terms of bytes. Oh well.